# Random UV offset on instances Geomerty nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

i'm working on a shingle roof with geometry nodes, using a few bezier curves to make the shape. I need to eliminate as much visible repetition as possible, hence the question;
how do i make it have a randomized offset to the UV map for the individual instances?

[image: Shingles]

Answer (score 0):

a person on the red blender discord gave me a suggestion, and it worked!
these are settings in the Shader tab

[image]